# How do I Control the size of a googlemap in iOS app + Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to build an iOS app that uses the googleMaps API. I have done great work until now but I faced an issue which is " I could not control the size of the map shown in the app". It takes always the full screen. Apparently, I'm missing something.

Here is snapshot of my code:

```
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate =  self

        /// Google maps stuff
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:-33.8688,longitude: 151.2093, zoom: 13.0)
        self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        /// Google maps stuff
```

most solutions were about adding a UIView ( UIView = myView )
then use this view like:

```
self.myView = mapView
```

or

```
self.myView = self.mapView
```

they did not work with me :(

Comment: Also I found some people saying use  CGRect.make or CGRect.init which both did not work also ??? CGRect.make is not avalible in latest update

Comment: If CGRect isn't working for you, you can try creating a UIView of required size in your viewcontroller, give that view GMSMapView class, create an outlet(say self.mapView) and use that object. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Bharat I have tried many solution on my own since I'm trying to learn swift and I did reach the solution and it was 100% exactly as you suggested , thanks again , appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinates.latitude,longitude:coordinates.longitude, zoom:15)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), camera: camera)
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    mapView.animate(toLocation: coordinates)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
})

mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = camera.target
mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
marker.title = "\(self.strLabelHeading)!"
marker.map = mapView
self.viewMap.addSubview(mapView)
```